# SpellChecker, Russian language

Tags: java, spell-checking

I’m using google-api-spelling-java jar library. And I need to use more languages to use, one of them is Russian. Where can I get the same library but with more languages?

Answer (score 0):

You could download source and add Russian ('ru') to Language class here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/source/browse/trunk/google-api-spelling-java/src/main/java/org/xeustechnologies/googleapi/spelling/Language.java

It would appear that this library is only a helper code, so I guess it should be enough:

```
public enum Language {
   DANISH("da"), GERMAN("de"), ENGLISH("en"), SPANISH("es"), FINNISH("fi"), FRENCH("fr"), ITALIAN("it"), DUTCH("nl"), POLISH(
        "pl"), PORTUGUESE("pt"), RUSSIAN("ru"), SWEDISH("sv");

   private final String code;

   private Language(String code) {
       this.code = code;
   }

   public String code() {
       return code;
   }
}
```

Then build your own jar. 
...
PROFIT! :)